# Changing text on UILabel from another View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using delegation to try to change the text from a UILabel in ViewController2.

In ViewController1.h I have:

```
@protocol WelcomeDelegate

-(void) updateLabelWithString:(NSString*)string;

@end


@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<WelcomeDelegate>delegate;
```

Inside ViewController1.m:

```
- (void)presentWelcomeAlert {

UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController2* contentVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2ID"];

[self.delegate updateLabelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome to the 11Health Family %@! We are here to accompany and support you through the journey as an ostomate. Our new Hydration Tracker is ready to follow your hydration levels. Tap 'Continue' to begin!", [dcsContext sharedContext].activeParticipant.firstName]];

UIViewController *rootVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
[rootVC presentViewController:contentVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Inside ViewController2.h I have:

```
#import "SignInViewController.h"


@interface WelcomePopoverViewController () <UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>
{
    SignInViewController *signInViewController;
}
```

In the viewDidLoad:

```
viewController1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
[viewController1 setDelegate:self];
```

My method in ViewController2.m:

```
- (void)updateLabelWithString:(NSString *)string {
welcomeLabel.text = string;
}
```

My issue is that the method above isn't getting called even when I call it from the first view controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit messy, sorry to say.....and you are re-instantiating ViewController1 in ViewController2....
If you only need to set that label once, then ditch all the delegate/protocol stuff and just call the method directly:

```
- (void)presentWelcomeAlert {
   UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   ViewController2* contentVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2ID"];

   UIViewController *rootVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
   [rootVC presentViewController:contentVC animated:YES completion:^ {
   [contentVC updateLabelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome to the 11Health Family %@! We are here to accompany and support you through the journey as an ostomate. Our new Hydration Tracker is ready to follow your hydration levels. Tap 'Continue' to begin!", [dcsContext sharedContext].activeParticipant.firstName]];
   }];
}
```

and then of cause expose that method in ViewController2.h:

```
-(void) updateLabelWithString:(NSString*)string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call this method no need to create delegate.

```
ViewController2 *obj=[[ViewController2 alloc] init];
[obj updateLabelWithString:@"title"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```